# Trying to exec javac.exe from a php script

Tags: java, php, apache, permissions, javac

i have a php script with the line:

```
exec( "javac Test.java" );
```

I get this error in the apache error log when I execute the script from the browser:

> 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

but I am pretty sure it's not a path issue, executing the java command works - it's in the same dir as javac - and executing javac works if I run the php script from the shell, not the browser.

The directory that Test.java resides in is generated by the script, with full permissions - 777

I am running xampp on Windows 10 on a Surface Notebook.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you will need to provided the absolute path to javac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the full path to `javac` for it to work correctly, e.g.

```
exec( "C:\path\to\javac Test.java" );
```

Depending on your system and Java version, the path could be similar to:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdkx.x.x\bin
```

Comment: What should I do in case of hosting to a server?

Comment: You should be able to do the same, just change the path to match the server path.